# Call to a member function empresas() on null - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two models: Empresa and Postulante. This relationship is Many-to-Many.

**Empresa Model**

```php
public function postulantes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Postulante::class);
}
```

**Postulante Model**

```php
public function empresas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Empresa::class)->where('empresa_postulante.activo', 1)->orderBy('empresa_postulante.created_at');
}
```

**PostulanteController** (get the Empresas for one Postulante)

```php
public function index()
{
    $usuario_actual = \Auth::user(); //obtengo los datos del usuario en sesion
    $usuario_id = $usuario_actual->id;
    $postulante = Postulante::where('pos_usuario', $usuario_id)->first();
    $empresas = $postulante->empresas();

    return view('postulantes/dash-postulante', compact('empresas'));
}
```

As there is no data in the relationship table (empresa_postulante), I get the following error message:

> Call to a member function empresas() on null

Comment: $postulante is a null value. Your first() method probably did not return any results. Check $postulante for data before calling empresas()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like:

```
$postulante = Postulante::where('pos_usuario', $usuario_id)->first();
```

...is not returning any results.